# FastAPI equivalent of Flask's request.form, for agnostic forms

Tags: python, fastapi

I try to migrate from Flask to FastAPI, and I was wondering if there is something similar to Flask's:

```
payload = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)
payload = {key:payload[key][0] for key in payload}
```

for FastAPI.

Until now I've found only some hacks, were you still had to implement one-by-one all the form's arguments to a function:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class FormData(BaseModel):
    alfa: str=Form(...)
    vita: str=Form(...)
async def Home(request: Request, form_data:FormData)
```

This example is of course better in readability than the standard form handling:

```
async def Home(username: str = Form(...), something_else: str = Form(...)):
```

But still it's quite restricting, due to the necessary declaration of all form fields.

Is there any other more agnostic & elegant approach?

Thanks in advance & I apologize if this a trivial question I've failed to find through googling :)

Comment: **Option 1** of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) demonstrates how to use `request.form()` in FastAPI to retrieve both Form data and Files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the underlying starlette [request](https://www.starlette.io/requests/) and use its request.form() method.  It requires [python-multipart](https://github.com/andrew-d/python-multipart) to work:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/example")
async def example(request: Request):
    form_data = await request.form()
    return form_data
```

Example of calling it:

```
C:\>curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/example" -d "hello=there&another=value"
{"hello":"there","another":"value"}
```

Comment: Why is this not the first solution to the form problem, even the form examples don't even work from the FastApi site. This really helped me a lot .

Comment: @clockwatcher If my HTML page has more <form> tags and different names, Can I use this name to choose a specific name for this?