# Unable to send WhatsApp messages using FastAPI and requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, webhooks, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am working on a project using FastAPI to handle incoming WhatsApp messages and respond to them. I've set up the webhook, and I can successfully receive messages. However, I'm encountering issues when trying to send a response back to the user using the WhatsApp Business API.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException, Query
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel
import requests




app = FastAPI()


VERIFY_TOKEN = "tourism"  

class WhatsAppEvent(BaseModel):
    message: dict


WHATSAPP_API_ENDPOINT = "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/***(Entered my phone number ID)/messages"
WHATSAPP_API_TOKEN = "***(Entered my API access token)"

@app.post("/")
async def handle_post_request(request: Request):
    # Process the incoming POST request here
    data = await request.json()
    print("Received POST request data:", data)


    # Send a response
    return {"status": "success", "message": "POST request received"}

@app.get("/")
def verify(request: Request):
    mode = request.query_params.get('hub.mode')
    challenge = request.query_params.get('hub.challenge')
    token = request.query_params.get('hub.verify_token')

    if mode and token:
        if mode == 'subscribe' and token == VERIFY_TOKEN:
            print("WEBHOOK_VERIFIED")
            return JSONResponse(content=int(challenge), status_code=200)
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Verification failed")
    return {"code": 200, 'message': 'test'}

@app.post("/incoming-message")
def receive_message(event: WhatsAppEvent):
    try:
        user_message = event.message['text']
        sender_id = event.message['sender']['id']

        bot_response = f'You said: {user_message}' #sending an echo message
        

        # Prepare response for WhatsApp
        response_data = {
            'recipient': {'id': sender_id},
            'message': {'text': bot_response}
        }

        send_whatsapp_message(sender_id, bot_response)

        return JSONResponse(content=response_data, status_code=200)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Error processing message: {str(e)}")
    
def send_whatsapp_message(recipient_id, message_body):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {WHATSAPP_API_TOKEN}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    data = {
        'phone': recipient_id,
        'message': {
            'text': message_body
        }
    }

    try:
        response = requests.post(WHATSAPP_API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, json=data)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raises HTTPError for bad responses

        print("WhatsApp API response:", response.text)  # Add this line for debugging

        return response.json()  # If you want to return the API response data
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print("HTTP Error:", errh)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=f"HTTP Error: {errh}")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print("Request Error:", err)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=f"Request Error: {err}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, reload=False, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

I have verified that the webhook is working (WEBHOOK_VERIFIED is printed in the console), and I can see the incoming messages in the logs. However, the send_whatsapp_message function does not seem to be sending messages successfully.

The response from the WhatsApp API is as follows:

```
WEBHOOK_VERIFIED
INFO:     2a03:2880:23ff:5::face:b00c:0 - "GET /?hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=1310749767&hub.verify_token=tourism HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Received POST request data: {'object': 'whatsapp_business_account', 'entry': [{'id': '**(My ID)', 'changes': [{'value': {'messaging_product': 'whatsapp', 'metadata': {'display_phone_number': '**(My number)', 'phone_number_id': '**(My Phone number ID)'}, 'contacts': [{'profile': {'name': 'Rishikesh Dasari'}, 'wa_id': '**(recipient Number)'}], 'messages': [{'from': '**(recipient Number)', 'id': 'wamid.HBgMOTE5MzkwMzYwMjYyFQIAEhgWM0VCMEMyRUU3MzQ4Q0VCNjFGQUIzRgA=', 'timestamp': '1705643757', 'text': {'body': 'hello'}, 'type': 'text'}]}, 'field': 'messages'}]}]}
INFO:     2a03:2880:20ff:b::face:b00c:0 - "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

I have double-checked the WhatsApp API endpoint, token, and the structure of the request, but I'm still unable to send messages. I suspect there might be an issue with my `send_whatsapp_message` function.

Can someone please review the code and provide insights on what might be causing the problem? Additionally, if there's a better way to handle sending WhatsApp messages in FastAPI, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: On a side note, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) on how to deal with JSON data in FastAPI. If you are expecting arbitrary JSON data, please make sure to use `try-except` blocks, in order to catch any likely exceptions - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) as well. I would also suggest using `httpx` with a reusable `client` session (within an `async def` endpoint) to make HTTP requests, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804), instead of `requests` (within a normal `def` endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems generally ok, and the issue might be related to how you're constructing the payload for the WhatsApp API. Let's review and make a few adjustments:

1. **Check for Valid WhatsApp API Endpoint:**
   Ensure that the `WHATSAPP_API_ENDPOINT` is correct and matches the WhatsApp Business API endpoint for sending messages.
2. **Update the `send_whatsapp_message` Function:**
   In your `send_whatsapp_message` function, it seems you are using `phone` as the key for the recipient's phone number. However, based on the WhatsApp Business API documentation, it should be `recipient_type` and `recipient_id`.

   Here is an updated version of the `send_whatsapp_message` function:

   ```py
   def send_whatsapp_message(recipient_id, message_body):
       headers = {
           'Authorization': f'Bearer {WHATSAPP_API_TOKEN}',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }

       data = {
           'recipient_type': 'individual',
           'recipient_id': recipient_id,
           'message': {
               'content': {
                   'text': message_body
               }
           }
       }

       try:
           response = requests.post(WHATSAPP_API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, json=data)
           response.raise_for_status()  # Raises HTTPError for bad responses

           print("WhatsApp API response:", response.text)  # Add this line for debugging

           return response.json()  # If you want to return the API response data
       except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
           print("HTTP Error:", errh)
           raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=f"HTTP Error: {errh}")
       except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
           print("Request Error:", err)
           raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail=f"Request Error: {err}")
   ```

   This modification aligns the payload structure with the WhatsApp Business API requirements.
3. **Verify WhatsApp API Token and Endpoint:**
   Double-check that your WhatsApp API token (`WHATSAPP_API_TOKEN`) and endpoint (`WHATSAPP_API_ENDPOINT`) are correct.
4. **Check WhatsApp API Response:**
   Print the response text from the WhatsApp API to get more insights into any error messages or issues:

   ```py
   print("WhatsApp API response:", response.text)
   ```

With these adjustments, your `send_whatsapp_message` function should be better aligned with the WhatsApp Business API requirements. After making these changes, observe the printed responses for any error messages and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Made the changes but still can't able to send the messages. Verified the Token and Endpoint but couldn't find the issue.